# How do I share code between projects, environments, and partners using vNext?

Tags: .net, deployment, nuget, development-environment, visual-studio-2015

I have an API solution that has a project I want to share with both partners and my front end solution. I have multiple testing environments that need to be updated before the code reaches production or gets released to partners. As I understand it, there is no concept of DLL references in vNext and everything must be published through a NuGet feed.

If I'm developing new functionality on the API shared project, I want to get those changes quickly on my development front end without affecting partners or other environments.

What is the best pattern to do this? Do I need a separate NuGet feed for each environment? It seems like there has to be a better way to isolate environments without separate NuGet feeds.

Comment: vNext is still in beta. Are you sure you want to be sharing production code that relays on that? That wouldn't be the smartest idea.

Comment: We are just getting set up now, by the time the code is production ready, vNext will have been released.

Answer (score 0):

NuGET package supports binaries for multiple environments within the package. See [here](http://brian-federici.com/blog/2013/4/17/automatically-target-multiple-frameworks-in-your-nuget-package) for more information.
Depending on what exactly architecture you may need to support you might be able to compile nuget package one same machine using msbuild parameters (if you need to support same operating system) or using some build process to build on different machines the solution to support different OSes.

On the other side vNext and next generation of .NET is expecting to support multi platform runs using [DNX](http://dotnet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dnx/overview.html). In brief using DNX you will be able to select platform and then run your application against the platform. DNX does that by downloading the NuGET packages extracting he right files from them for the right platform, then builds and runs your application against them.